# Wifi with multiple password

Tags: apache-2.2, networking, mysql, php

I'd like to allow  every user have their own specific wifi password that generated from database. It just like star-buck system, customer purchased their food they able to get they specific password. Is there any way to allow router verify wifi password that stored at database?

Answer (score 1):

This is called WPA2 Enterprise authentication. You will need a radius server for your user database, access points that support WPA2 Enterprise, and a certificate that your clients trust.